# SPI transaction timeout linux device driver

Tags: spi, driver, linux

I am stuck for last 3 days at a point.

I am working on eink device driver with msm8960 qualcomm chipset.

`Scenario:`
In file: kernel/arch/arm/mach-msm/devices-8960.c

I cannot verify the `use of spidm_channels" and "spidm_crci"` and the corresponding entries.(msm8960 pro)(copied from some reference code)
How to verify if the values of corresponding `start and end` are correct??
I have datasheet for msm but cannot find any reference.

I have added the following code in order to create a new gsbi resource in file as:

```
static struct resource resources_qup_spi_gsbi9[] = {
    {
            .name   = "spi_base",
            .start  = MSM_GSBI9_QUP_PHYS,
            .end    = MSM_GSBI9_QUP_PHYS + SZ_4K - 1,
            .flags  = IORESOURCE_MEM,
    },
    {
            .name   = "gsbi_base",
            .start  = MSM_GSBI9_PHYS,
            .end    = MSM_GSBI9_PHYS + 4 - 1,
            .flags  = IORESOURCE_MEM,
    },
    {
            .name   = "spi_irq_in",
            .start  = GSBI9_QUP_IRQ,
            .end    = GSBI9_QUP_IRQ,
            .flags  = IORESOURCE_IRQ,
    },
    {
             .name   = "spidm_channels",
            .start  = 3,
            .end    = 4,
            .flags  = IORESOURCE_DMA,
    },
    {
            .name   = "spidm_crci",
            .start  = 12,
            .end    = 13,
            .flags  = IORESOURCE_DMA,
    }, 
};
```

The reason for having this doubt is that our DMA operation is failing with the error : 
from logs:

```
<6>[    0.764932] wait_for_ready: I/F Ready.^M
<7>[    0.765176] s1d13522_ spi9.0: setup mode 0, 16 bits/w, 51200000 Hz max --> 0^M
<3>[    1.756630] spi_qsd spi_qsd.9: msm_spi_process_transfer: SPI transaction timeout^M
```

and then if we try to perform another DMA operation it gives the following error:

```
<3>[    6.773355] s1d13522if_cmd: wait_for_ready: I/F busy bit stuck^M
<7>[    6.775400] s1d13522_ spi9.0: setup mode 0, 16 bits/w, 51200000 Hz max --> 0^M
<4>[    6.775583] ------------[ cut here ]------------^M
<4>[    6.775614] WARNING: at /home/anshul_10605816/hip_mirror_2330_code/kernel        /lib/list_debug.c:32 __list_add+0x58/0x78()^M
<4>[    6.775644] list_add corruption. prev->next should be next (c0d5124c), but was 00100100. (prev=edf643b8).^M
<4>[    6.775675] Modules linked in:^M
<4>[    6.775766] [<c00149b8>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x11c) from [<c007c818>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64)^M
<4>[    6.775827] [<c007c818>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64) from [<c007c8b0>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x2c/0x3c)^M
<4>[    6.775888] [<c007c8b0>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x2c/0x3c) from [<c02a9538>] (__list_add+0x58/0x78)^M
<4>[    6.775919] [<c02a9538>] (__list_add+0x58/0x78) from [<c001e3d4>] (start_ready_cmd+0x84/0x13c)^M
<4>[    6.775980] [<c001e3d4>] (start_ready_cmd+0x84/0x13c) from [<c001e704>] (msm_dmov_enqueue_cmd_ext_work+0x148/0x284)^M
<4>[    6.776041] [<c001e704>] (msm_dmov_enqueue_cmd_ext_work+0x148/0x284) from [<c0094e0c>] (process_one_work+0x27c/0x484)^M
<4>[    6.776072] [<c0094e0c>] (process_one_work+0x27c/0x484) from [<c0095224>] (worker_thread+0x210/0x3b0)^M
<4>[    6.776133] [<c0095224>] (worker_thread+0x210/0x3b0) from [<c00990c0>] (kthread+0x80/0x8c)^M
<4>[    6.776194] [<c00990c0>] (kthread+0x80/0x8c) from [<c000f108>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)^M
<4>[    6.776224] ---[ end trace da227214a82491b8 ]---^M
<3>[   11.766732] spi_qsd spi_qsd.9: msm_spi_process_transfer: SPI transaction timeout^M
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

If any more code information is required please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The resource setup depend on your platform, not only the driver.

An idea could be to validate your SPI bus before using it with the target chipset directly. I suggest to use spidev interface and a user space code to send something on the bus and observing the result on a logical analyser or an oscilloscope. I usually do that to validate new boards.

The list_add corruption is suspicious, but difficult to say more at that point.